# Android emulator 2.0 toolbar unclickable in linux (KDE)

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, kde-plasma

The version of the Android emulator bundled with Android Studio 2.0 has a focus problem under KDE (4.14.15). When user clicks on a virtual button (power button, display rotation button, volume button, etc), the toolbar hides and no action is performed. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that is only affects KDE and it isn't a general Linux problem?

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot test on other machine, so I prefer to be specific. And as I did not found a similar problem report on the net and there is a GNOME screenshot in other question about problem rotating the screen but not mentioning the toolbar itself I suppose the problem is WM related.

Comment: This question probably belongs on [su] as it isn't programming related

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007 . Is it possible to migrate the question there?

Comment: Just create new question on other SE site (Super User in given case) and copy paste content of this question into it. No migration is needed. Do not forget to delete this question after all.

Answer (score 1):

Until it is really fixed you can do a workaround:

1. In the 'System settings' go to the 'Window Management'-> 'Window rules'.
2. Create 'New...' rule.
3. Give it a name 'Emulator toolbar'
4. In the window matching tab select 'Window types' : 'Splash screen'
5. In the window matching tab select 'Window title' : 'Exact match' 'Emulator'
6. In the tab 'Appearance & Fixes' check 'Window type', select 'Force', 'Normal Window'
7. OK, and 'Apply' in the parent window.

The toolbar will now function normally and it will be docked on the right side of the emulator window.